# Flickering while removing blur css class with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, transition

I've got a problem, my img element is blurred with CSS3, after refreshing the website I'd like the image to remove the blur class from it with jQuery. Everything works fine, however, there is a strange flicker while removing the blur class. The problem's visible on Chrome. I've already tried:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0);
```

and

```
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden
```

Here's [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eoaqq8b7/)

Comment: Every example of animated blur I've seen are impacted by this little movement flickering. I guess that's completely due to a browser's somewhat flawed implementation, and IMO there's not much to be done against it

Comment: I can't agree with you, in my humble opinion it's caused by jQuery removeClass();

Comment: No. Inspect the image, and remove the `blur` class manually from the DOM. You'll achieve the exact same thing.